# React JS / Material UI - Breadcrumbs with dynamic Ids in between path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, breadcrumbs

I am new to react and trying to create breadcrumbs with dynamic Ids between path.

My props to component is:

```
const breadcrumbsData = {
  path: "facilities/65743/facilitycontact",
  breadcrumbNameMap: {
    "/facilities": "Facility",
    "/facilities/:facilityId": ":facilityId",
    "/facilities/:facilityId/facilitycontact": "Facility Contact"        
  }
};
```

code which renders breadcrumbs is

```
<Breadcrumbs arial-label="Breadcrumb">
  {paths.map((path, index) => {
    const url = "/" + paths.slice(0, index + 1).join("/");
    const last = index === paths.length - 1;
    return last ? (
      <Typography color="inherit"> {breadcrumbNameMap[url]} </Typography>
    ) : (
      <Link to={url}>{breadcrumbNameMap[url]}</Link>
    );
  })}
</Breadcrumbs>
```

I tried different approaches but could not figure out how to do this. It works perfect without Ids in between path. for example

```
const breadcrumbsData = {
  path: "facilities/facilityprofile/facilitycontact/workcontact",
  breadcrumbNameMap: {
    "/facilities": "Facility",
    "/facilities/facilityprofile": "Facility Profile",
    "/facilities/facilityprofile/facilitycontact": "Facility Contact"
  }
};
```

P:S -  Tried 'match' but did not go anywhere with that, and my use case is I am manually passing path from props.

Here is complete code

[Code Sandbox - BreadCrumbs using react and material UI](https://codesandbox.io/s/v3ky6vr7j0)

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure why you need to this that way, but here is an ad hoc solution. Don't use your `breadcrumbsData.breadcrumbNameMap` directly to find the name. Pre-process it and generate your map with simple string replace.

For example, define a utility to pre-process the map:

```
generateNameMap = (id, idKey, map) => { 
  // takes the actual id i.e. '65743', 
  // the template key that need to be replaced with i.e. ':facilityId'
  // and the initial map i.e. breadcrumbsData.breadcrumbNameMap
  const clone = {};
  Object.keys(map).forEach(k => {
    clone[k.replace(idKey, id)] = map[k].replace(idKey, id) // replace the template in both key and value with actual id
  })
  return clone;
}
```

Now define your `breadcrumbNameMap` to use that utility rather than using `breadcrumbsData.breadcrumbNameMap` directly:

```
const breadcrumbNameMap = this.generateNameMap(paths[1], ':facilityId', breadcrumbsData.breadcrumbNameMap);
```

Here is a demo:

```js
const generateNameMap = (id, idKey, map) => {
    const clone = {};
    Object.keys(map).forEach(k => {
      clone[k.replace(idKey, id)] = map[k].replace(idKey, id)
    })
    return clone;
}


const breadcrumbNameMap = generateNameMap('65743', ':facilityId', {
        "/facilities": "Facility",
        "/facilities/:facilityId": ":facilityId",
        "/facilities/:facilityId/workcontact": "Facility Contact",
        "/facilities/facilityprofile/facilitycontact/": "Work Contact"
});
console.log(breadcrumbNameMap);
```